# jQuery-UI :: How to increase drag speed?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Perhaps the question doesn't make much sense on its own, so let me explain...
I'm working on an interactive map application which, among other features, allows you to move around a map when zoomed in. Simply click and drag. And this feature was done by using jQuery-UI.

My problem is that the drag, by default, is done by a factor of 1. Which means that moving the cursor by 1 pixel drags the map by 1 pixel. What I need is to have a 'multiplier' (probably in the range of 1-10), so that by moving the cursor by 1 pixel, the map would drag by the multiplier's value (expressed in pixels).
How can I do this and still rely on the jQuery-UI plug-in?

Thanks

Comment: just add that 'multiplier' somewhere in your code..?

Comment: Exactly, @gpasci. Have the multiplier as a variable.

Comment: Andrei, youll have to post some specific code here on SO. or even a jsfiddle or jsbin demo. help us to help you. and think about future generations browsing for a similar question - ending up here with a broken link

Comment: Cool site @AndreiOniga.  I found your question/answer useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the drag event of the draggable ui object to manipulate positions and obtain faster dragging.

I've created a very basic implementation you can adapt to your map..

http://jsfiddle.net/3QgJS/

Comment: Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: your url is working fine is safari and chrome.. not sure if i understand what you mean with "it will stall"

Answer (score 4):

In the interest of making sure answers contain code (and not just links), and to improve on the existing answer (less glitchy), here is what I came up with:

```
var mult = 1.3;
$("#dragme").draggable({
    drag: function (event, ui) {
        ui.position.top += (ui.offset.top - ui.originalPosition.top) * mult;
        ui.position.left += (ui.offset.left - ui.originalPosition.left) * mult;
    }
});
```

Set `mult` to `0` for normal dragging speed.

If you set `ui.position`, you don't need to use jQuery's `css` method.  Using these formulas, the position will not jump when you try to drag a second time (since it is based off of the offset and original position).  You should be able to easily adjust it to include a container as well by checking `ui.position` and the height and width of the container, and resetting `ui.position` in the same way (except without the multiplier).

Check the demo, based off of the existing answer by @gpasci: http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/LMD7v/